# Posting Complex Object through Ajax to MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have been fiddling with MVC for quite some time now and I'm interested in creating a mini-application that records all cd-contents under one cd. My main hurdle for now is how can I pass on a list of Contents to a Cd.class along with other property values?

```
public class Cd
{
    public int CdId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; } 
}

public class Content
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
 $.ajax({
 url: '/cd/addCd',
 type: 'POST',
 data:$('form').serialize()
    });

@using(Html.BeginForm()){
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.CdId)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.CdId) <br/>
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Description)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Description)<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
```

}

Please do note that the CdId and Description values are already passed on by the Serialize function of ajax - only the Contents property is the one I'm having trouble grasping the idea

**Update**

I solved my query by creating an ajax snippet that sends the serialized data to the controller:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:54004/Cd/AddCd',
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            contentType:'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        })
        .success(function () { })
```

**With the following formData obj:**

```
   var formData = {
        'Description': "Learning Visual Studio 2012",
        'CdId': 1,
        'Contents': [{ "Id": 1, "Name": "Video #1", "ContentType": "Mp4" }, { "Id": 2, "Name": "Video #2", "ContentType": "Mp4" }]
    };
```

Now the controller is now receiving the full set of Cd entity value along with its Content.
Hope this could serve useful to someone in the future.

Comment: good job. i see where you went.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to achieve what you want is to remove the JQuery and replace your HTML.BeginForm with Ajax.BeginForm

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm()){
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.CdId)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.CdId) <br/>
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Description)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Description)<br />

@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Contents[0].Id)<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Contents[0].Name)<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Contents[0].ContentType)<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Contents[1].Id)<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Contents[1].Name)<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Contents[1].ContentType)<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
}
```

Now your Submit button will post to a method Named after your View and Send the entire model

Comment: Yes, thanks for the info, but what I'm trying to do is to submit along with the Id and Description is a list of Contents. Will an array work with this?

Comment: yes, it will. array binding is done by indexing. I'll include and example

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm pleased to know that it will work. I'll be fiddling with this one while I await for your example. Hopefully we can close this query and help others who are in trouble as well.

Comment: @KevinIsNowOnline, this WAS my next example. We can make this into a loop if you are passing a populated model or want a specific number iof controls... If I'm missing something, please clarify.

Comment: I have solved my query as described on the update above. Thank you for helping me come up with an idea on how to tackle this kind of concerns. Again, thanks for constructively helping me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building the JSON object manually by iterating over, there is an interesting alternative in the form of knockoutmvc (Knockout integrated with MVC)

Check the example - http://knockoutmvc.com/BetterList

It sends a full JSON object without writing any extra code.